# Merge [down-votes] into [downvoting]

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, retag-request

I've suggested a synonym, but [downvoting] seems the better tag.  Could [down-votes] be merged into [downvoting]?

Currently:

- [[downvoting]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/downvoting) × 47
- [[down-votes]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes) × 217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, done, and I merged all approved synonyms on meta while I was in there.

Comment: Would make sense to do `[up-votes]` and `[upvoting]` as well for consistency?

Comment: I believe you did the inverse of what I was asking: [downvoting] is now a synonym of [down-votes] rather than being the "preferred" tag? I'm probably worrying too much about a subjective, small (in the grand scheme) issue, but that wasn't obvious from your answer.

Comment: @Gnome I'm unsure how Atwood's system works, Gnome, but in most systems the primary tag, or current preferred tag, is fixed until. For data-consistency purposes. So adding a synonym to the tag down-votes was the solution that probable cost less time.